# Mock functions called by functions in Jest

Tags: jestjs

**my-funcs.js**

```
export const a = () => 5;
export const b = () => 10;
export const theSum = () => a() + b();
```

**my-funcs.test.js**

```
import { a, b, theSum } from "./my-funcs"

describe('Test sum', () => {
    test('The sum is correct', () => {
        expect(theSum()).toEqual(15);
    });
});
```

Now imagine that functions `a` and `b` do complex work, and I want to mock them such that I can mock their return value in my test without running their complex code, to make sure that `theSum` is correctly summing?

How can I do this with all of these functions exported from the same file?